# There is a commercial tool like Xen + Remus?

Tags: virtualization

I have a project where we need a completely redundant system like the one offered by Remus with a Xen virtualization system. I wondered if there is a system like this one built by VMWare or some other company because the project is a very critical one and we do not want to have to wait that a bug is fixed by "the community" and money is not a problem.

What Remus does is to build a completely redundant system where you can shutdown one machine and the other continues the work where the other left it maintaining the network connections opened, etc

Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [VMWare Fault Tolerance](http://www.vmware.com/products/fault-tolerance/overview.html) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We use [InMage DrScout](http://www.inmage.com/products/core-products.html) for XenSource.

We just started using this, so no comments on how good(or bad) it is.

Comment: Looks like this has nothing to do with my question because this is a tool for doing backups isn't it?

Comment: All HA tools have to create a backup first. Remus does the same. http://blog.xen.org/index.php/2009/04/02/project-remus-released/

Answer (score 0):

[Marathon](http://www.marathontechnologies.com/) [everRun VM for Citrix Xenserver](http://www.marathontechnologies.com/high_availability_xenserver.html)

I haven't used it myself, but it's another option, and it's been round for a number of years.